# How to check if data needs to be seasonally differenced in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, arima, seasonality

I am forecasting data using ARIMA. I would like to know if there is any test to check if seasonal differencing is needed in the ARIMA model.

I know R uses Canova Hansen test, but does MATLAB provide anything similar to that? Also, is there an easy way of predicting if seasonally differenced model would give better results than the one without seasonal differencing?

I would like to take the decision before fitting the model and estimating the data. Currently I am using BIC to check the performance and evaluate the best model. But the process is really slow. So I would like to know beforehand if i should seasonally difference the data or not.